# Agregar elemento no definido a ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, filtro

Tengo el siguiente formulario en Django para usarlo en un filtro

```
class DocentesForm(forms.Form):
    docentes= forms.ModelChoiceField(
       required=False,
       queryset=Docentes.objects.all(),
       label="Docentes"
    )
```

Modelo Docente

```
class Docente(model.Models):
    nombre = model.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellido = model.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Modelo Estudiante

```
class Estudiante(model.Models):
    nombre = model.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellido = model.CharField(max_length=30)
    docente = models.ForeignKey(Docente, null=False, blank=False)
```

Necesito una opción para poder filtrar a los estudiantes que no tengan asignado ningún docente, pero el queryset me regresa los objetos docentes que existen.

Necesito decir que muestre los estudiantes donde docente asignado sea igual a "Sin asignar".

"Sin asignar" debe ser una opción del filtro que para Django regrese `None`

Por ejemplo:

- Sin asignar
- Pepito
- Fulano
- Sultano

Comment: cuales son tus modelos ?

Comment: docente y estudiante, ya los agregue a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso un Estudiante siempre tendría un Docente asignado, pues en `docente = models.ForeignKey(Docente, null=False, blank=False)` estás indicando que es obligatorio ya que indicas que no puede ser ni nulo ni vacío (si no pones lo contrario es así por defecto). Si quieres que sea opcional:

```
docente = models.ForeignKey(Docente, null=True, blank=True)
```

Posteriormente el formulario quedaría así:

```
class DocentesForm(forms.Form):
docentes= forms.ModelChoiceField(
   required=False,
   queryset=Docentes.objects.all(),
   label="Docentes",
   empty_label="Sin asignar"
)
```

Te aconsejo actualizar tu versión de Django, pues estás usando una antigua. Actualmente `ForeignKey` debe de llevar explícito `on_delete = models.CASCADE`.